# Getting data from mysql between two dates for a joomla project

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I must modify a simple project to display some values in a different way.

I got a MySQL database, in which are stored reservations.

I want to get all data from  a reservation, selecting the room and the period.

that's my query:

```
function getReservation($idroom,$date){
    $db=JFactory::getDbo();
    $query=$db->getQuery(true);
    $datecheck=$date->format('%Y-%m-%d');

    $query
         ->select($db->quoteName(array('idroom','status','idguests','nguests','value_paid','value_pending','value_full','valid_from','valid_to','today','extra_ids','nchilds')))
         ->from($db->quoteName('#__bookitbooking'))
         ->where($db->quoteName('idroom')."=".$idroom)
         ->and ( $db->quoteValue($datecheck) . "BETWEEN" . $db->quoteName('valid_from') . "AND" . $db->quoteName('valid_to'));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $res = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $res;
}
```

But  the `and` clause  seems to not have effect, in fact when I get the count of reservation stored from the query, I got all that matches with the `$idroom` value.

With that function I want to know if for a particular date exists a reservation, and if it exists I want to get all the parameters.

Where's my mistake?

Obviously I can obtain at maximum just one reservation object.

Comment: You need to place `AND` _inside_ the SQL statement – right now, you have it outside of the string. Only reason this does not throw a syntax error is that PHP has an `AND` operator as well.

Comment: in that way ? `->where(($db->quoteName('idroom')."=".$idroom)
    ."and".($datecheck."BETWEEN".$db->quoteName('valid_from') AND $db->quoteName('valid_to')));`

Comment: No, I’m talking about the AND between the two date columns …

Comment: in this way : `->and($datecheck."BETWEEN".$db->quoteName('valid_from').'and'. $db->quoteName('valid_to'));` I got the same behaviour

Comment: if joomlas query builder doesn't support BETWEEN use two simple conditions instead: $datecheck >= valid_from  and $datecheck <= valid_to ...

Comment: @VMai I got this message now "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<=' (T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL)"

Comment: I didn't wrote complete code, I wanted to give a hint :-) But a look at the joomla query builder documentation showed me, that CBroe is right, but missed the quoteValue part: `->and ( $db->quoteValue($datecheck) . "BETWEEN" . $db->quoteName('valid_from') . "AND" . $db->quoteName('valid_to'));` should do it.

Comment: @VMai I edited the query according to your solution. I got the same result. The problem still resist

Comment: Without a bit of sample data, the desired result and the result you get (only minimum of columns) we can't help you.

Comment: I don't think that data will explain better this situation, but as soon as possibile I'll edit my question with some examples. The problemi is that the code after `->and` doesn't affect the query.  I got all the reservations (ignoring the dates) for each room.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your syntax.  The "and" is assumed in the second where clause, where you check the dates, when using the core Joomla DBO class.  Change the second where clause line to:

```
->where(INSERT DATE QUERY HERE);
```

*** EDIT ***

Another couple of things I noticed are the date formatting and your method for wrapping values in quotes for the table name and the $datecheck variable.  Not to say the date formatting you're using shouldn't or won't work, but traditionally I've always formatted my dates using MySQL syntax.  Try this, which accounts for the MySQL date formatting and using the DBO method intended for wrapping table names:

```
function getReservation($idroom,$date){
    $db=JFactory::getDbo();
    $query=$db->getQuery(true);
    $datecheck= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query
         ->select($db-quoteName(array('idroom','status','idguests','nguests','value_paid','value_pending','value_full','valid_from','valid_to','today','extra_ids','nchilds')))
         ->from($db->quote('#__bookitbooking'))
         ->where($db->quoteName('idroom')."=".$idroom)
         ->where( $db->quoteName($datecheck) . "BETWEEN" . $db->quoteName('valid_from') . "AND" . $db->quoteName('valid_to'));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $res = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $res;
```

}

Comment: In this way? :   
         `->where($db->quoteName('idroom')."=".$idroom)
         ->where ( $db->quoteValue($datecheck) . "BETWEEN" . $db->quoteName('valid_from') . "AND" . $db->quoteName('valid_to'));
    $db->setQuery($query);`